# Counting labelled graphs with k edges and n vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a way to count labelled graphs (simple graphs - without loops and without multiple edges) with k edges and n using combinatorics methods without having to draw them?

For example - How many labelled graphs are there with 3 edges over the vertices {a, b, c, d, e, f}.

Please just provide me with a way (if there's any) and I would post an answer to the example question

Comment: There are $\tbinom{n}{2}$ possible edges, out of which you choose $k$, so this gives a total of $\tbinom{\tbinom{n}{2}}{k}$ graphs.

Comment: Are the edges labeled as well?

Comment: Has someone found the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** An edge is between *two* vertices. And assuming the graph is simple, we cannot choose the same vertex pair twice. Then first of all, how many unordered vertex pairs are there when we have $6$ vertices? (Unordered means $\{a,b\} = \{b,a\}$ for all $a,b$) Secondly, how many ways are there of choosing three distinct vertex pairs among them? Note that since it's labelled graph, we don't have to consider isomorphism.